# How to embed ffmpeg and ffprobe to a python gui.exe file in Windows or Mac?

Tags: ffmpeg, embed, ffprobe

I prepared a Pyhton Gui script in Windows that gets a subtitle then converts an audio file. But at the end of the script I realized that the script uses the ffmpeg from my computer's local ffmpeg and didn't give any error. But, when I try in another computer that doesn't include ffmpeg, it's given the error in the terminal below:
`pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work Processing text 1/2 pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work Error occurred: [WinError 2] System cannot find the specified file`

I tried many ways such as:

`pyinstaller -F --add-data "./ffmpeg/*;./ffmpeg/" gui.py`

`pyinstaller -F --add-data "C:\Users\sbura\Desktop\gom\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe;ffmpeg" --add-data "C:\Users\sbura\Desktop\gom\ffmpeg\ffprobe.exe;ffmpeg" gui.py`

OR

tried to gui.spec file adding:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          binaries=[('C:\\Users\\sbura\\Desktop\\gom\\ffmpeg_bin\\ffmpeg.exe', 'ffmpeg.exe'), 
                    ('C:\\Users\\sbura\\Desktop\\gom\\ffmpeg_bin\\ffprobe.exe', 'ffprobe.exe')],
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          ...
```

I also created a folder with the name of "ffmpeg" where I put the files of ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe.

Also I added to my code that:

```
import sys
from pydub import AudioSegment

def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)

AudioSegment.converter = resource_path('ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe')
AudioSegment.ffprobe = resource_path('ffmpeg\\ffprobe.exe')
```

But any of these didn't work. Thank you for your help.